# Download file from my App and move it to a local folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have created a JSON file in my app. Is there any way that I can move it, or download it from my app to the files folder and inside the Shortcuts folder? Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your app doesn't have access to your user's global folders. You can use FileManager to save it to disk, but it will be in a folder that is specific to your app.

To save a file to a folder outside of your app's sandbox, you'll need to present a [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) and allow the user to choose which folder to give your app access to.

Comment: Are there any good examples for this that you would suggest I look into?